# is IBM maximo MxLoader is available for Apache open office

Tags: openoffice-calc, maximo

i am trying upload data into maximo using MxLoader. I know that .xlsm files can be opened by openoffice calc. is that possible to load MxLoader in openoffice calc?

Answer (score 0):

MxLoader was designed to be used with Microsoft Excel. You can load `.xlsm` files in LibreOffice or OpenOffice, but you will not see the MxLoader ribbon.

[image: MxLoader ribbon]